# 3.5 LCD does not start on my Rasberry pi-2 Model B windows 10

Tags: raspberry-pi, lcd

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.  I also have a [3.5 inch Touch Display LCD](http://www.waveshare.com/3.5inch-rpi-lcd-a.htm) for Raspberry Pi.  I am running the Raspberry Pi with the attached Touch screen, but it only shows a white screen.  It is connected via the GPIO port.  I have installed Windows 10 IOT OS.

1) How can it connect to Raspberry Pi?

2) Why is it only White(Blank) Screen showing?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the 3.5 Inch LCD Display Modules require special drivers that do not come standard with the Raspbian OS.  They either come packed with the Module itself (Usually for Raspbian) or are downloadable from the web.  I'm not aware of any drivers for Windows 10, but with a datasheet you may be able to configure it for yourself ([This](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=109479) may serve as a starting point for that kind of project if that's what you really want to do.)

To answer your two questions:

(1) The Display connects to the Raspberry by via the GPIO Port.  You have already done this.

(2) The screen is white because this is the default state of the module when it is plugged in and not utilised.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! I solved it last night. Here is the answer on my post: [How do you get a waveshare 3.5 inch touch LCD to work with Raspbian Jessie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498911/how-do-you-get-a-waveshare-3-5-inch-touch-lcd-to-work-with-raspbian-jessie/35612160#35612160). Hope this helps!