# How do you get a waveshare 3.5 inch touch LCD to work with Raspbian Jessie?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, touchscreen, lcd

I have a waveshare 3.5 inch touch LCD display and I m trying to get it working with the latest version of Raspbian A.K.A Raspbian Jessie. I followed futurice.com 's tutorial on getting it to work (tutorial is titled I'd like some LCD on my pi) and it worked on Raspbian Wheezy just fine. All I get now is a blank white screen. All help is greatly appreciated! (I must use the official Raspbian Jessie image without NOOBS from the Raspberry pi website.) I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Mobel B +.

Answer (score 0):

From the product page:

> **Why the LCD doesn't work with my Raspbian?** To use the LCD with the
>   Raspberry Pi official image, driver should be installed first. Please
>   refer to the user manual. However, for the first testing, you may want
>   to use our provided image directly. **Why the LCD still doesn't work
>   with the Waveshare provided image?** Make sure the hardware connection
>   is correct and connects fine. Make sure the image in TF card is burnt
>   correctly. The PWR will keep on and the ACT will keep blinking when
>   the Raspberry Pi starts up successfully, in case both of the two LEDs
>   keep on, it is possible that the image was burnt incorrectly OR the TF
>   card was in bad contact.  **Which power supply should I use?** It is
>   strongly recommended to use a stand-alone 5V/2A power adapter, because
>   the PC's USB port might doesn't have enough power to support the Pi
>   and LCD. For more info, please check the wiki page

You can find more info on [their wiki](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)).

It sounds like you either need to use their Raspian image, or install the driver for this display on your existing Raspian install:

```
wget http://www.waveshare.net/w/upload/7/73/LCD-show.tar.gz
tar xvf LCD-show.tar.gz
cd LCD-show/
sudo ./LCD35-show
```

Comment: I tried that but the screen is still white and now I can't use Raspbian because the steps from Waveshare end up installing their own custom kernel which doesn't work for Raspbian Jessie. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If the screen still doesn't work after installing the driver waveshare suggest, get in touch with their support team directly. Perhaps there's something extra that their wiki is missing at the moment ? There's not much more I can help with other than the what's publicly available.

Comment: I haven't used the waveshare screen, but I've used a few Adafruit TFT displays and I remember the documentation being much better and they also have a Raspian Jessie image that works, so if (distributor shipping) time and budget isn't a huge issue, it might be worth considering ? I'm hoping waveshare will get in touch and help debug the issue though

Comment: Hey I found out the answer :) I posted it below. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi there, Mine screen works 10s after boot. I did the steps above and on their site. It just freezes... what can I do?

Comment: @Mike Unfortunately I don't have access to this LCD module. I would double check the power and data lines (e.g. check the specs for how much power the LCD draws and make sure the RPi is using at least 2A, make sure the GPIO pins are aligned appropriately and firmly connected, etc.) to get the simple/obvious issues out of the way. Maybe it's worth double checking connections with a multileter for loose/dodgy solder points. If everything is fine and you still get freezes get in touch with the manufacturer, could be a dodgy module. (If you have a second screen, test that too, also a second RPi ?)

Comment: Thanks for the input, Im using pihut 2A power adapter and I can only visually check for bad soldering etc. but im fairly sure its not the case because I can use other device in those pins without a problem. Is it worth using more than 2A ? (RPI3)

Comment: I think the RPi3 draws more power (can go up to 2.5A). You can try a 2.5A power supply: can't hurt if you have more amps, the devices will use as much as it needs. Hard to tell if that's the actual problem thought, but good to tick things that could go wrong off the list